# python MySQLdb error?

Tags: python, mysql

while i am trying to connect with python MySQLdb, i get an 'Invalid Arguments' error.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd = "",db = "test")
```

what is the reason for getting such a error?.

But, the following code with _mysql works fine.

```
db=_mysql.connect("localhost","root","","test")
```

Comment: Just a note - "localhost" is the default host for MySQLdb, so you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import MySQLdb.cursors

DATABASE= MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='username', passwd='password', db='databasename', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect ("localhost","root","","test")
```

?

(random reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm )